# HTML comment cause issue in functions.php script root

Tags: php, functions, html

I noticed HTML comment tag `<!-- -->` will cause issue on themes *functions.php* script if it is in the root of script(not inside a function).
I was working on my themes functions.php to add some *Easy Digital Downloads* action/filter, which i realized purchase button will continue to loading and doesnt add product to basket.
after clearing an html comment that was in the root of script,issue solved. i need to know whats wrong with having HTML comment in functions.php root ?

(BTW my wp site is hosted on a cpanel shared host)

Comment: Please include some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `functions.php` is loaded before WordPress has sent the HTTP response headers. If you have raw HTML content in that file, even a HTML comment, then that will be sent immediately, triggering PHP's built-in HTTP headers.

Now, WordPress doesn't know about this and tries to send the headers as usual. And that will cause an error message like "Headers already sent …". This message comes with information about the file and line that created the first output, so it's rather easy to debug.

Long story short: Don't create raw output in the `functions.php`, use template files for that.

Comment: as edd add button is ajax ,how can i see output error in chrone developer tools?should i enable an option in config.php or something else?

Comment: @amin That's a completely different question. :) Please use a new, separate question for that.